# How can I add a ExpandoObject to an already existing ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, expandoobject

Here is my code:

```cs
dynamic App = new ExpandoObject();
//App names are SAP, CRM and ERP 

//App names - adding static
//App.SAP = new ExpandoObject();
//App.CRM = new ExpandoObject();
//App.ERP = new ExpandoObject();
```

In the last 4 lines, I am adding an `ExpandoObject` static as I know the app names previously. But I want to do this dynamically.

I can do for the properties dynamically:

```cs
AddProperty(App.SAP, "Name", "sap name");
AddProperty(App.SAP, "UserID", "sap userid");
AddProperty(App.SAP, "EmailID", "userid@sap.com");
AddProperty(App.SAP, "GroupOf", "group1, group2, group3");


public static void AddProperty(ExpandoObject expando, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    // ExpandoObject supports IDictionary so we can extend it like this
    var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
    if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        expandoDict[propertyName] = propertyValue;
    else
        expandoDict.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
}
```

But I need to add this object `App.SAP` to this App which is also an `ExpandoObject`, so I can add `App.CRM` or `App.ERP` dynamically later on.

Comment: Is this [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SKAViO) meets your requirement?

Comment: So from your question, you didn't want to declare/define `App.SAP`, but wanted to create `App.SAP` dynamically?

Comment: exactly. I wanted to create App.SAP dynamically. Let me try your demo.

Comment: that worked perfectly. Young shun. You can write the answer and i shall mark them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get

> `ExpandoObject` doesn't have a definition for `SAP`...

with this approach:

```
AddProperty(App.SAP, "Name", "sap name");
```

as you didn't *declare* the `SAP` in `APP` ExpandoObject.

---

Instead, you can try to modify the `AddProperty` method by providing the `parentName` and deal with the nested object.

```cs
AddProperty(App, "SAP", "Name", "sap name");
AddProperty(App, "SAP", "UserID", "sap userid");
AddProperty(App, "SAP", "EmailID", "userid@sap.com");
AddProperty(App, "SAP", "GroupOf", "group1, group2, group3");
```

```cs
public static void AddProperty(ExpandoObject expando, string parentName, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    // ExpandoObject supports IDictionary so we can extend it like this
    var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
    if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(parentName))
    {
        ((IDictionary<string, object>)expandoDict[parentName])[propertyName] = propertyValue;
    }
    else
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> child = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { propertyName,  propertyValue }
        };
            
        expandoDict.Add(parentName, child);
    }
}
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VElTmS)

Comment: Excellent! I also added the ListProperty(App) It would be nice if you could add the answer into the sample program   https://dotnetfiddle.net/kKdbo9